# How can I make a snap scroller in a web page's inner section use the parent scroller when it reaches its start or end position?

Tags: css, sections, scroll-snap

I have implemented a snap scroller within a page's inner section. The issue I'm facing is that when it reaches the starting or ending point, it stops. I want it to use the parent scroller whenever it reaches its start or end position.

I attempted to implement a snap scroller in a webpage's inner section within a React.js project. I expected it to continue scrolling and utilize the parent scroller when reaching its start or end position. However, it stopped at these points.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.